# Python - regex on each line of file

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have few `*.txt` files which contains sentences per line. There are some text inside parentheses. I would like to remove them including parentheses and put them into the new file separated by new line. So far what I've tried

```
import re
import glob

with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out_file:
    for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):
        with open(file, 'r') as in_file:
            for line in in_file:
                out_file(re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', line))
                out_file('\n')
```

During execution, I got following error:

```
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

out_file is not a function that you can "call". You need to call it's method `write`.
Change

```
out_file(re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', line))
out_file('\n')
```

to

```
out_file.write(re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', line))
out_file.write('\n')
```